# Get the client id of the message sender in socket.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

on the server side i got

```
socket.on('chat', function (data) {
    io.sockets.socket(data.clientid).emit('chat', {
        msg: data.msg,
        senderid : senderid
    });
});
```

How can I get the get the senderid without the sender having to post their clientid through with the message?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It turns out I can just use socket.id of the user sending through a msg to get their clientid, such as:

```
  socket.on('chat', function (data) {
      io.sockets.socket(data.clientid).emit('chat', {
          msg: data.msg,
          senderid : socket.id
      }); 
  });
```

Originally I thought I could just fetch the clientid by doing :

```
  io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
     clientid = socket.id;
```

But clientid will be the last person who connected in this instance, not the last person who sent through a chat

Comment: I'm sorry but saving the socket.id to a declared var after 'connection' will do the trick! working great for me

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest sending over a username (make sure it's unique) and keeping an object of client ids associated with usernames in memory.