# Why does socket.disconnect disconnect the wrong user?

Tags: socket.io

My website has an IM with several users connected.  From my client I wish to disconnect a particular user.  Here is the code I am trying:

```
  // client side
function deleteUser(delCallsign)
     {
          delCallsign = delCallsign.toUpperCase();
            socket.emit('deleteuser', delCallsign); // send it to the server for delete
     }

// server side
socket.on('deleteuser', function(callsign)
   {
        socket.disconnect(usernames[callsign]);
      io.sockets.emit('updateusers', usernames);
    });
```

Using an alert, I have verified that I'm calling the server side function with the username I wish to disconnect.  But what happens is that I get disconnected, not the user specified.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Does the array contains the socket.id of the individual you are trying to disconnect? Also this might be relevent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25976501/socketio-disconnect-client-by-socket-id

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say - the usernames array hold the user names.

Comment: but is there something down the line that pass the socket.id of the user to be disconnected... socket.disconnect() needs a socket.id parameter otherwise it will fall to its default behavior which is close the sockets.

Comment: Well, no and that explains why it is disconnecting me instead of the desired user.  When a user is connected they are stored in the socket session with socket.username = username; and to the array with usernames[username] = username;  So how would I go about getting the socket.id of the user I want to disconnect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On user connection you should record its socket.id which you would then call for deletion

```
io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
      // Asign socket.id to variable 
      // socket.id;
});

socket.on('deleteuser', function(callsign) {
      io.sockets.connected[usernames[callsign].id].disconnect();
      io.sockets.emit('updateusers', usernames);  
});
```

This is roughly the idea.

Based on those post:

[SocketIO: disconnect client by socket id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25976501/socketio-disconnect-client-by-socket-id)

[Get the client id of the message sender in socket.io?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519617/get-the-client-id-of-the-message-sender-in-socket-io)

-- More Relevent --

A little bit old but the same principals applies

[how do I store socket resources from specific users with socket.io?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048873/how-do-i-store-socket-resources-from-specific-users-with-socket-io)

Comment: Thanks Musk, appreciate the help.